# Paypal return variables on success page

Tags: post, paypal, return

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO**
I am simply trying to display the results of a Paypal subscription signup. I see the issue of not being able to see the POST variables is a common issue.

I have tried many different ways to do this and I see a common solution is to use:

`<input id="rm" name="rm" type="hidden" value="2">`

This does not work.

I have tried emailing myself $_POST and $_REQUEST variables and they are empty.

However, my code that detects the txn_type $_POST variable works, since my variables appear in my database. After writing to the database, it is supposed to show a receipt, but does not.

Here's the button code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypalemail@gmail.com">

<!-- Specify a Subscribe button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<!-- Identify the subscription. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Monthly Featured Listings">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">

<!-- Set the terms of the regular subscription. -->
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="0.01">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">

<!-- Set recurring payments until canceled. -->
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">                          
<input name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/user/register/index.php" type="hidden">
 <input name="return" value="http://www.example.com/user/register/index.php" type="hidden">
<input name="cancel_return" value="http://www.example.com/user/register/index.php?payment=cancelled" type="hidden">
<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="http://www.example.com/images/register-and-pay-now.png" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
 <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
```

Since my database code works, I can only guess that Paypal is sending the information correctly, but I can't get it to show up in the web page.

**My QUESTION**
How can I show successful $_POST variables in my page after the redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Well, my guess is that the variables that you are receiving and storing to the database are hitting the `notify_url`.

These variables are the IPN variables and are not supposed to be shown on any web page.

In order to get information on the specified `return` URL you have to access the PDT data.
Read more about PDT [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/)